# "Rake spec" failing most tests, but "rails s" working fine on Diaspora source

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rspec, diaspora

I've got source of Diaspora cloned and I've got a working local pod that seems to run without a hitch. But when I run `$ rake spec` some initial tests pass and then all of them start failing. Also, what I found interesting was that they fail at different points each time `rake spec` is run.

They all fail with the error:

```
An error occurred in an after hook
  ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::ConnectionBad: PQsocket() can't get socket descriptor: ROLLBACK
  occurred at /home/darshan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@diaspora/gems/activerecord-3.2.16/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:650:in `async_exec'
```

Postgres' log said:

```
could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
unexpected EOF on client connection
```

Comment: did u run $ rake db:test:prepare

Comment: Yes, @RahulSingh, I did.

Comment: post your `database.yml`

Comment: @gotva, here it is: http://pastebin.com/1pjxd8A0

Comment: (strange I don't have a good suggest) What about trying to run a console or server in test env `RAILS_ENV=test rails c` and run some simplest queries. does it work?

Comment: @gotva, seems to work without any problems. _Even_ `RAILS_ENV=test rails s` works fine.

Comment: I haven't met similar situation. If app works in test env correctly and some tests are passed then the problem in tests. Do you use not trivial things in them? Maybe paralel testing, maybe some gems for integration testing.

Comment: Looks like a connection or performance problems rather than the configuration. Is your test database located on remote host ?

Comment: @DarshanRai did you get to make it work? have the same issue

Comment: @ishwr I switched to using MySQL and that worked for me. It was a very strange bug and I'm not sure what caused it.

Comment: I have this issue as well. I'm using version 0.18.1 of the `pg` gem (the latest at time of writing) and my spec runs regularly start failing with this error part way through and never recover.

Comment: Here's a [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23626372/rspec-pgconnectionbad-pqsocket-cant-get-socket-descriptor) to this issue that's not Diaspora specific.

Comment: I had this same problem; for me it happened during a long-running `delayed_job` that imports some records from a CSV file. Like @DarshanRai, I switched to MySQL, and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem and found that by using the local unix socket file, rather than accessing the Postgres server via localhost, the problem seems to have gone away.

To achieve this, remove the `host: localhost` from your database.yml file, and re-run `rake spec`. This defaults back to the local socket file (usually .s.PGSQL.5432 in /tmp or /var/run/postgres, depending on your platform.)

Comment: I tried this but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: This fixed our test suite errors with minitest + rails 4 running on Amazon EC2 Ubuntu box.  Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the [same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23626372/rspec-pgconnectionbad-pqsocket-cant-get-socket-descriptor/29290256#29290256). I tried reverting to `pg` version `0.18.0` instead of `0.18.1`, and that seems to fix it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `postgres.conf` and change `ssl = true` to `ssl = false`

I found the fix for this issue [here](https://wiki.diasporafoundation.org/Testing_workflow#Troubleshooting_testsuites_launch) and it worked for me.

Comment: I would not recommend this for production.